# Unexpected Javascript Behavior

Tags: javascript, css, html, html-table

I tried making the classic game of snake and walls using table only (contrary to canvas). Everything worked fine and there are no errors or bugs in the initial run.

The first problem is that when the snake collects second golden block, it leaves a fragment, but as per code, that color should become black after the snake leaves the cell.

Second, The golden dots stop appearing on the screen even when their locations are set and accessible.

Line 257 :  showSnakeHead() --> Shows the snake

Line 205 : checkCollision() --> checks collisions

---

### Javascript Code

`engine.js`

```
// <div id="output"></div>
// <div id="display"></div>


// bind things together
function startEngine(){

// SIZE OF GAME
    SETTING__rows   = 22;
    SETTING__cols   = 40;
    GAME__START     = 0;
    GAME__PAUSE     = 0;
    GAME_SPEED      = 350;
    GAME_END        = 0;
    GAME_SCORE      = 0;

// For Enhanced Testing
    // SETTING__rows    = 200;
    // SETTING__cols    = 200;
    GAME_SPEED      = 50;


// APPEARANCE
    COLOR__border   = "#696969";
    COLOR__snake    = "#FF6347";
    COLOR__target   = "#FFDF00";
    COLOR__default  = "black";

// CONTROL
    SNAKE_DIR       = "UP";
    SNAKE_X         = 0;
    SNAKE_Y         = 0;
    SNAKE_LENGTH    = 0;
    SNAKE_PATH      = [];
    SNAKE_TARGET    = 0;
    SNAKE_TARGET_X  = 0;
    SNAKE_TARGET_Y  = 0;
    SNAKE_TMP       = [0,0];

// FUNCTIONS
    makeGrid();
    paintGrid();
    makeSnake();

// Game function
    setInterval(runGame, GAME_SPEED);
}


// main functions
function makeGrid(){
    var x = "<table >";
    for(var i=0; i<SETTING__rows; i++){
        x+= "<tr>";
        for(var j=0; j<SETTING__cols; j++){
            x+= "<td class='gameBox' id='__"+j+"-"+i+"'>";
            x+= "</td>";
        }
        x+= "</tr>";
    }
    x+= "</table>";
    $("#output").html(x);
    // console.log();
}

function paintGrid(){
    for(i=0; i<SETTING__rows; i++){
        for(j=0; j<SETTING__cols; j++){
            if(j==0 || j==SETTING__cols-1){
                $("#__"+j+"-"+i).css("background-color",COLOR__border);
            }

            if(i==0 || i==SETTING__rows-1){
                $("#__"+j+"-"+i).css("background-color",COLOR__border);             
            }
        }
    }
}

function makeSnake(){   
    // calculate the mid
    var midCol = parseInt(SETTING__cols)/2;
    var midRow = parseInt(SETTING__rows)/2;

    // Store Location
    SNAKE_X = midCol;
    SNAKE_Y = midRow;

    // paint the snake
    $("#__"+midCol+"-"+midRow).css("background-color",COLOR__snake);


    // Create Head of snake
    SNAKE_PATH.push([midCol, midRow]);
    SNAKE_LENGTH ++;
}

function startGame(){
    GAME__START = 1;
    console.log("start");
    console.log(GAME__START);
}

function pauseGame(){
    GAME__PAUSE = 1;
    console.log("pause");
    console.log(GAME__PAUSE);
}

function resumeGame(){
    GAME__PAUSE = 0;
    console.log("resume");
    console.log(GAME__PAUSE);
}

function runPauseResume(){
    // GAME__START
    if(GAME__START == 0){
        // start game
        startGame();
    }
    else if(GAME__PAUSE == 0){
        pauseGame();
    }
    else if(GAME__PAUSE == 1){
        resumeGame();
    }
}


// Bindings
$("#output").on('click', function(){
    runPauseResume();
});

// Key Bindings
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    // space 
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
            runPauseResume();       
        }
    // left
        if(e.keyCode==37){
            SNAKE_DIR = "LEFT";
            console.log("LEFT");
        }
    // right
        if(e.keyCode==38){
            SNAKE_DIR = "UP";
            console.log("UP");
        }
    // up
        if(e.keyCode==39){
            SNAKE_DIR = "RIGHT";
            console.log("RIGHT");
        }
    // down
        if(e.keyCode==40){
            SNAKE_DIR = "DOWN";
            console.log("DOWN");
        }

    // Prefect Default action of keys
    e.preventDefault();
});


// FINAL GAME FUNCTIONS
function runGame(){
    if(GAME__START == 1 && GAME__PAUSE == 0 && GAME_END == 0){
        // move in direction
        direction = SNAKE_DIR;

        if(direction == "DOWN"){
            SNAKE_X = SNAKE_X;
            SNAKE_Y = SNAKE_Y+1;
            checkCollision();
            // showSnakeHead();
        }
        else if(direction == "UP"){
            SNAKE_X = SNAKE_X;
            SNAKE_Y = SNAKE_Y-1;
            checkCollision();
            // showSnakeHead();
        }
        else if(direction == "RIGHT"){
            SNAKE_X = SNAKE_X+1;
            SNAKE_Y = SNAKE_Y;
            checkCollision();
            // showSnakeHead();
        }
        else if(direction == "LEFT"){
            SNAKE_X = SNAKE_X-1;
            SNAKE_Y = SNAKE_Y;
            checkCollision();
            // showSnakeHead();
        }

        showSnakeHead();
        console.log(direction);
        console.log("New Head  = " + SNAKE_X + ", " + SNAKE_Y);
    }
}

function checkCollision(){
    if(SNAKE_X == 0 || SNAKE_X == SETTING__cols-1 ){
        alert("GAME OVER !");
        GAME_END = 1;
    }
    if(SNAKE_Y == 0 || SNAKE_Y == SETTING__rows-1 ){
        alert("GAME OVER !");
        GAME_END = 1;
    }

    // if get the target
    if(SNAKE_TARGET_X == SNAKE_X && SNAKE_TARGET_Y == SNAKE_Y){

        // disappear the target
        $("#__"+SNAKE_TARGET_X+"-"+SNAKE_TARGET_Y).css("background-color",COLOR__default);  

        // create new target
        SNAKE_TARGET = 0;

        // increment Score
        GAME_SCORE ++;

        // Increase Snake Length
        SNAKE_LENGTH ++;

        // Increase length of stored locations
        SNAKE_PATH.push([SNAKE_TARGET_X, SNAKE_TARGET_Y]);

        console.log("Score : " + GAME_SCORE);

        $("title").text("Score - " + GAME_SCORE);
    }

    if(SNAKE_TARGET == 0){
        // Create target to eat
        SNAKE_TARGET_X = getRandomInclusive(2,SETTING__cols-2);
        SNAKE_TARGET_Y = getRandomInclusive(2,SETTING__rows-2);

        // paint target
        $("#__"+SNAKE_TARGET_X+"-"+SNAKE_TARGET_Y).css("background-color",COLOR__target);

        // mark that target now exist
        SNAKE_TARGET = 1;
    }
}

// most complicated function
function moveSnake(){

}

// shows movement of snake
function showSnakeHead(){

    // shift array by one
    for (var i = SNAKE_PATH.length-1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
        // disappear the tale
        $("#__"+SNAKE_PATH[SNAKE_PATH.length-1][0] +"-"+SNAKE_PATH[SNAKE_PATH.length-1][1]).css("background-color",COLOR__default);
        console.log("DSIAPPEARING TALE");

        // shift array by one
        SNAKE_PATH[i]   = SNAKE_PATH[i-1];

        // new head
        SNAKE_PATH[0] = [SNAKE_X,SNAKE_Y];
    }

    // show rest of snake
    for(var j=0; j < SNAKE_PATH.length; j++){
            // console.log(SNAKE_PATH[i][0],SNAKE_PATH[i][1]);
            console.log("DISPLAY !---------------------------------------------------");
            console.log(SNAKE_PATH[j]);
            $("#__"+SNAKE_PATH[j][0] +"-"+SNAKE_PATH[j][1]).css("background-color",COLOR__snake);       
            // console.log(SNAKE_PATH[i]);
    }

    // $("#__"+SNAKE_X+"-"+SNAKE_Y).css("background-color",COLOR__snake);
}

function getRandomInclusive(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

HTML
(nothing cool here)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Coding Playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/game.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-3">Snake game !</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple snake game .</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>Contribute to the development on github</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div id="output" class="style0"></div>
</div>

<div id="display">

</div>



</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/engine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){   
    startEngine();
});

</script>
</html>
```

---

images of bugs
[image: Left over of snake]
[image: golden dots not appearing]

Comment: I fear nobody is going to go through 300 lines of code. You should try and locate the problem to reduce the number of lines.

Comment: Line 257 : showSnakeHead() --> Shows the snake

Line 205 : checkCollision() --> checks collisions

Comment: @YashKumarVerma no, *no one is going to read your wall-o-text code dump*: adding line numbers aren't enough. Reduce the problem to a *minimal example*. You will likely find the solution yourself in the process of doing so, and learn to write better code in the process. If you don't manage to find a solution, you will find people more willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

> The first problem is that when the snake collects second golden block, it leaves a fragment, but as per code, that color should become black after the snake leaves the cell.

Not sure, but I expect the problem is in `showSnakeHead`:

```
// shift array by one
for (var i = SNAKE_PATH.length-1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
```

You shouldn't need an entire loop like this to shift the array by one. Use `shift` / `unshift`.

> Second, The golden dots stop appearing on the screen even when their locations are set and accessible.

Your code to generate a new target doesn't check to see if that cell is already occupied by the snake! When that happens, it will be invisible because its immediately overwritten by the snake drawing code, and nothing sets it back to the correct color.

Comment: But as far as it shifts the array, what's the possible reason behind left overs of snake?